# AWS RDS Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just followed a tutorial to create an RDS database. Since the time of creating my will I be charged every hour for which my database instance is active or will I be charged for everytime I make a query to the database?.

Comment: Check the Amazon [RDS Pricing Information](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/)

Comment: You can use [Amazon Aurora Serverless for MySQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html) for intermittent and unpredictable workloads. It automatically scales based upon usage and can even automatically turn off when not in use.

Comment: Thank you John. I look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you're charged for every hour your RDS instance is running, and (broadly) not how much you actually use it. There may be some small charges for large volumes of queries, but keeping the instance running is the main cost.

However if you're a new customer you can have a small RDS instance free for a year. Look for 'free-tier eligible' on the management console.

Comment: does this mean, from the time I created my database I am being charged or does the instance stop running after a certain time of inactivity?

Comment: No, the instance keeps running (and adding to your bill) until you turn it off. There is a distinction between 'stop' and 'terminate' to turn it off: I think 'stop' means 'turn the database off but keep the data', and you'll be charged a little for the data storage, and 'terminate' means 'delete everything except backups'.

Comment: It's not really safe for Amazon to automatically turn off an idle database: they have no idea what applications are out there that might suddenly want access to it at short notice. So they leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you Rup. The reason I am asking is because I have a to create  website for a small business and their usage is very little and the need for the database  to awake always is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

AWS has [detailed pricing category for different DB](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) which should be clear enough. Taking mysql "On-Demand DB Instances" as an example, it charges based on the type and duration, however for RDS T3 DB instances which uses [unlimited mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html) it may involve extra fees if your average CPU usage exceed baseline.